# In Jquery how to redirect to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing a search function using range slider using Jquery&Ajax in Php.

I can get the data from the database and display in same page but I need to display data in another page.

My Index page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            tr { border:1px solid #066;}
            tr th { border:1px solid #eeeeee; padding:5px; background:#e1e1e1;}
            tr td { border:1px solid #eeeeee;}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#slider-range").slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1000,
                    values: [0, 500],
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#amount").val("Rs." + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Rs." + ui.values[ 1 ]);
                        var from = ui.values[ 0 ];
                        var to = ui.values[ 1 ];
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "get_data.php",
                            data: "from=" + from + "&to=" + to,
                            success: function (html) {
                                $("#response").html(html);
                                //window.location="index1.php";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                $("#amount").val("Rs." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - Rs." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:280px; padding:10px;">
            <h5>Price Range:</h5>
            <div id="slider-range"></div>
            <input type="text" id="amount" class="ttt" style="margin-left:70px">
            <div id="response"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My get_data code is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("details", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $formprice = $_POST['from'];
    $toprice = $_POST['to'];

    $query = "SELECT * from details where hallcapacity between '" . $formprice . "' and '" . $toprice . "'";
    $res_cart = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row_cart = mysql_fetch_array($res_cart)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_cart['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_cart['address']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_cart['city']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

In Index page after success function I used window.location function but on moving slide it redirects to other page with out getting values.Please give any suggestions.

Comment: then why you are using jquery ajax?

Comment: thats i'm asking if you want to redirect page then why you using ajax-jquery

Comment: Also set the `data: "from=" + from + "&to=" + to` values in the url when click to next page button, and detect that params on page load, Another alternate solution is use pushHistory api to change the url without page refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to pass parameter to another page via `window.location` you can do this:

```
winndow.location.href = 'new_page.php?param1=one&param2=two&...';
```

and get the params in new page with php:

$param1 = $_GET['paramm1'];
   $param2 = $_GET['paramm2'];

Answer (score 0):

Any how you will try this for redirection after AJAX success:

```
var a = data;

window.location.href ="window.location.href="index.php?data="+a";
```

In index1.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["data"])){
echo $_GET['data'];
}
?>
```

Comment: @Janani : did you got my answer

Comment: I used this it is redirecting to other page but without getting any value it is redirecting @Priyank

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the data to be shown in another page,there is no need for you to use `ajax`.You could pass the parameters you need through the `url` and Get the values of the parameters in the corresponding page function.You could `redirect` as such

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "Rs." + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Rs." + ui.values[ 1 ] );        
    var queryString="firstArg="+fArg+"&secondArg=sArg";
    window.location.href="/ControllerName/Classificate/?"+queryString
}
```

In the corresponding page controller get the arguments from the url and process the result.Hope that helps mate.. :)